# OpenCL local memory size and number of compute units

Tags: opencl

Each GPU device (AMD, NVidea, or any other) is split into several Compute Units (MultiProcessors), each of which has a fixed number of cores (VertexShaders/StreamProcessors). So, one has `(Compute Units) x (VertexShaders/compute unit)` simultaneous processors to compute with, but there is only a small fixed amount of `__local` memory (usually 16KB or 32KB) available per MultiProcessor. Hence, the exact number of these multiprocessors matters.

Now my questions:

- (a) How can I know the number of multiprocessors on a device? Is this the same as `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS`? Can I deduce it from specification sheets such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units?
- (b) How can I know how much `__local` memory per MP there is available on a GPU before buying it? Of course I can request `CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE` on a computer that runs it, but I don't see how I can deduce it from even an individual detailed specifications sheet such as http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/7000/7970/Pages/radeon-7970.aspx#3?
- (c) What is the card with currently the largest `CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE`? Price doesn't really matter, but 64KB (or larger) would give a clear benefit for the application I'm writing, since my algorithm is completely parallelizable, but also highly memory-intensive with random access pattern within each MP (iterating over edges of graphs).

Comment: Try running the device query in the samples given by AMD/NVIDIA in the SDK. If you want to know device queries of specific device there are many out there who have put it online.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS` should give you the number of ComputeUnits, otherwise you can glance it from appropriate manuals (the [AMD opencl programming guide](http://developer.amd.com/sdks/amdappsdk/assets/AMD_Accelerated_Parallel_Processing_OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf) and the [Nvidia OpenCL programming guide](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=nvidia%20opencl%20programming%20guide&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/NVIDIA_OpenCL_ProgrammingGuide.pdf&ei=0WoTT7ehGsWOsAbx_qDfDg&usg=AFQjCNFYT0UJ0pWPyufjcn050UH_0nghjw&cad=rja))
2. The linked guide for AMD contains information about the availible local memory per compute unit (generally 32kB / CU). For NVIDIA a quick google search revealed [this document](http://www.nvidia.com/content/PDF/fermi_white_papers/NVIDIA_Fermi_Compute_Architecture_Whitepaper.pdf), which gives the local memory size as 16kB/CU for G80 and G200 based GPUs. For fermi based cards (GF100) there are 64kB of onchip memory availible, which can be configured as either 48kB local memory and 16kB L1 cache or 16kB local memory and 48kB L1 cache. Furthermore fermi based cards have an L2 cache of upto 768kB (768kB for GF100 and GF110, 512kB for GF104 and GF114 and 384kB for GF106 and GF116, none for GF108 and GF118 according to wikipedia).
3. From the informations above it would seem that current nvidia cards have the most local memory per compute unit. Furthermore it is the only one with a general L2 Cache from my understanding.

For your usage of local memory you should however remember that local memory is allocated per workgroup (and only accessible for a workgroup), while a Compute Unit can typically sustain more then one workgroup. So if your algorithm allocated the whole local memory to one workgroup you will not be able to use achieve the maximum amount of parallelity. Also note that since local memory is banked random access will lead to alot of bank conflicts and warp serializations. So your algorithm might not parallize quite as good as you think it will (or maybe it will, just mentioning the possibility).

With a Fermi based card your best bet might be to count on the caches instead of explicit local memory, if all your workgroups operate on the same data (I don't know how to switch the L1/local Memory configuration though).

Comment: That's a very interesting point you rise there, my algorithm is indeed consuming all the local memory per compute unit. How many workgroups should be running on the same compute unit to make it run at (near) full speed?

Comment: Also, that L2 cache sounds interesting, but I don't get it. Modern devices have like 32 compute units on them, and Fermi gives a 768KB L2-cache, that's only 24KB per compute unit (compared to 64KB L1)? I.e. there's less L2 than L1 cache??? Or am I misunderstanding the point of this cache?

Comment: Addendum to my first comment above: each workgroup will consist of a few hundred work items.

Comment: @user1111929: GF100 and GF110 based cards have up to 16 CUs, so it's 48kB of L2/CU, so the L2 has the same size as the sum of all L1 caches (remember that L1 can be configured as either 16kB or 48kB/CU). This makes it useful if all your workgroups operate on roughly the same dataset. For the number of workgroups: How much workgroups you need for optimal speed depends on your kernel. The more threads you have the better latencies can be hidden. Maximum threads/CU is 768 for G80, 1024 for G200 and 1536 for GF100 and between 1200 and 3200 (6200 for extreme low end) for AMD cards (depending on

Comment: the the positioning of the card in the generation, instead of the generation) according to the documentations I linked above. I generally try to go for at least half that value for nvidia, somewhere around the high end maximum for high end cards (so about 1200) for amd, which is typically enough to hide most latencies. Note that the number of threads (and therefore workgroups) is also limited by the number of registers used per threads and the number availible per CU. Of course if you get your workgroup big enough you might get away with using one workgroup.

Comment: Radeon cards also have L2 cache.  But I don't think any of the cache memory is programmable in OpenCL anyway?  On Radeon 5xxx series at least, L1 is used for broadcast from constant memory.

Comment: @Chinasaur: According to the programming guide only reads from constant memory and texture accesses are cached, so it's not a *full* cache, which caches all data access. That might have changed with gcn (Radeon 7xxx series) though, I'm not sure. Without knowing the algorithm the OP is trying to use I had to assume that modifying access to local memory (or cached memory) was needed. And what do you mean about cache memory not beein programmable? As any caches they are implicitly used when accessing data which uses them, so the trick is finding a usepattern which maximizes cache reuse.

Comment: @Chinasaur: Of cause they aren't explicit, they are caches afterall. I don't see how caching constant reads only could be more useful. You can trash the cache just as easily if you have enough data and a bad access pattern (particularly since 5xxx, 6xxx cards have much less cache then fermi). The reason only readonly memory is cached is very likely not usefulness, but design efficiency, since it is much easier to cache only readonly memory (no cache coherency problems). From what I read the 7xxx series caches reads and writes, so AMD seems to agree with me about the usefulness.

Comment: @Chinasaur: If writable memory was cached it might be necessary to ensure that all CUs see the same data, so some sort of cache coherency would be needed (depending on what the OpenCL spec says it might be possible to get away without that coherency (since the order of those writes is unspecified anyways), but I wouldn't count on that). A cache for readonly data only can never be stale (since the memory can't change), so no cache coherency is necessary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7058/discussion-between-chinasaur-and-grizzly)