# Where can I find graphics card specifications for openCL programming?

Tags: opencl

I would like to buy a new card, but I cann't find a lot information about cards. 
I'm searching for
 - private memory size
 - local memory size
 - constant memory size
 - texture memory size

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: There are some tables with generic info about [NVidia](http://radeon.ru/reference/nvidia/cardtable/) and [Radeon](http://radeon.ru/reference/cardtable/) (both are in Russian; written in mid-2012). Global memory sizes and rates are listed; also GFlops and core configuration are given. Similar tables are in Wikipedia for every GPU generation, e.g. [GF 6xx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeForce_600_Series). What kind of tasks do you want to solve on GPU?

Comment: There is some info in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866222/ about how to convert Compute Unit count into memory sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You may have more luck researching a card's architecture, rather than researching specific cards.  Often graphics cards of a particular generation have varying amounts of identical hardware features on-chip.  For example, the architecture of a core is often the same across a series of cards, but the number of cores in a product can be unique.

I also recommend reading AnandTech graphics card reviews.  They tend to go into great detail when they benchmark graphics cards.